# Does Qt has any library/APIs which can be used for trimming/cropping to create audio/video thumbnails?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, thumbnails

Need to create thumbnails for audio & video files. Is there any built-in or programmatic way in Qt to be able to do it?

<sub>Related: [Execute ffmpeg to Crop Audio in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15200373/514235)</sub>

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for based on the question, but you might look at [Qt Multimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtmultimedia-module.html) to see what's available.

Comment: @MrEricSir, suppose we have an audio or a video file of several MBs, then I would like to create a viable thumbnail for it. For example, if I can get an audio play of first few seconds. Similarly I can get a gif of first few seconds of video. I also referred this related post: [Qt audio editing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12434485/514235).

Comment: If you want a robust and codec independent software as an end product consider using QtAV. Qt itself does not know anything about decoding video and audio files and is heavily based on what the operating system has installed. Qt allows you to obtain frames, etc. therefore it should be possible to use only Qt APIs to create thumbnails (i. e. you can load the video with QMediaPlayer and obtain a frame to create the thumbnail, if the codecs are present).